# What are some ways to override local babelrc configurations?

Tags: babeljs, babel-cli, babel-core

I have a .babelrc file with certain configurations that I want to override in select situations (not environment-related). Unfortunately, babel documentation is not very clear on order of precedence for configs that are passed(i.e., .babelrc, babel-loader, babel.transform, babel-cli, etc).

Also, is it possible to pass query-parameters or options to babel presets such as es2015 when using babel-cli?